# Command-output (stdout, stderr) to the web in Python

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

Recently I have developed a short Python script using the Flask framework to start a process over HTTP (see [**here**](https://github.com/rpoisel/scripts/tree/master/web_start)). Now there is the question for an adequate technology to "pipe" the standard streams (I am especially interested in *stdout* and *stderr*) of started processes to the Web.

What would you say is the most suitable way to accomplish this? First I thought of websockets to fit perfectly. But then it seemed to me that most implementations veil their connected clients. I think that I need this information in order to be able to send the output to all of them.

**Edit**: I think that my question was a bit unclear: I want to see the output of the executed command in a web-interface. So I have to "convey" data from stdout/stderr of the executed process via HTTP somehow to the web-interface(s). It might be possible that the started command may run for some (longer) time. The example which invokes the `dd` command is not representative as it does not output anything in the given setting. And sure, I would have to use the output of the `subprocess.Process` class and objects (e. g. by using the `communicate()` method).

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what your goal is. Your code has this. Perhaps that's a clue?

```
   current_app.process = subprocess.Popen(
            ['dd', 'if=/dev/zero', 'of=/dev/null'])
```

Trawl through the docs for subprocess.  You'll find you can specify stdout and stderr.
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

One strategy might be to capture stdout/err to file then rewrite that file to your http response.

Comment: Thank you for your post! I think that it is not applicable to my situation as it would mean to reload the whole file with every request. I want to see what the process outputs in real time. Sure, I would have to interface my process using the `subprocess.Popen` object's methods.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that will work (and is non-blocking, can serve multiple clients) is using Twisted:

Connect a ProcessProtocol

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html

to a Twisted WebSocket server

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython

Disclosure: I am author of Autobahn.

Comment: Thank you for that hint! :-) I think that the [Broadcasting example of Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/developers/tutorials/broadcast) will do the job. I'll keep you informed as soon as I've tried it out.